# What is home row for touch typing on a йцукен layout?

Tags: транслитерация

In English touch-typing on a qwerty keyboard, the default position of the fingers is asdf (left) and hjkl (right). The Russian keys extend further to the right, owing to the greater number of letters.

Is there a standard home row positioning for touch-typing on a йцукен keyboard? If so, is it with the left fingers on фыва and right fingers on ролд, or left fingers on фыва and right fingers on олдж, or something else?

Thanks,

Comment: It's ФЫВА ОЛДЖ.

Comment: Small nitpick: as far as I know, the default position for the right hand isn't hjkl but jkl; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_typing#Home_row) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_typing) for instance, or look at your keyboard where there should be a small bump on the F and J keys (where the index fingers go). HJKL is common only among vim and angband users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The home row *asdf* and *jkl;* corresponds to *фыва* (left) *олдж* (right) on russian (Russian Cyrillic) layout.